# Css in master page affected the content page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class labelin master page

```
 label{
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            color: #2E4972;
            font-family: Calibri;
        }
```

In the content page I have used a label tag with style like

```
<label ID="lblpendingcount" CssClass="labels" Style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 13px;">Levelwise Approval Pending Counts</label>
```

How could I applied a actual style.please help me .I dont know how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the CSS-Class as an attribute of the name "class" to the label.

```
<label ID="lblpendingcount" class="label" Style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 13px;">Levelwise Approval Pending Counts</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a `labels` class and add it to the `label` element in your question, this `labels` class will have the styles in your `style=""` declaration? You also want all `label` elements, regardless of class to have the styling you initially put in your question? If so, please see below:

**CSS:**

```
label {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #2E4972;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

label.labels {
  text-decoration: underline; 
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label id="lblpendingcount" class="labels">Levelwise Approval Pending Counts</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

//use internal style method like

label#lblpendingcount{

text-decoration:underline;

font-size:13px;

```
  `enter code here`
```

//place the actual style here..

}
if it didnt work use **!important**